# python3 re.sub is no longer greedy when anchored to the end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am in the process of converting python2 (2.7.14) to python3 (3.9.6) and noticed this odd thing.  I want to make sure a URL has an ending slash, so I run:
`url = re.sub('/*$', '/', url)`

In python2, this would indeed add a slash to the end of the url if there was no slash there.  If there was a slash there already, then it would leave the one slash there.

Now, in python3, regardless of if there is an ending slash or not, it will put a slash at the end, so if it already had a slash, there will be two after the command.

What am I missing?

You can reproduce this with:

```
import re
for s in ['no_slash', 'with_slash/']:
    r = re.sub('/*$', '/', s)
    print('before: {0}'.format(s))
    print('after:  {0}'.format(r))
    print('-----------')
```

For python2, this will result in:

```
before: no_slash
after:  no_slash/
-----------
before: with_slash/
after:  with_slash/
-----------
```

For python3:

```
before: no_slash
after:  no_slash/
-----------
before: with_slash/
after:  with_slash//
-----------
```

I tried it at https://www.online-python.com/ also, same python3 result.

Comment: The regex still is greedy, the issue is that it matches *twice* - once for the trailing slash (replacing it with a slash), and once for the empty string at the very end (also replacing it with a slash).  A *negative lookbehind* is one solution - `(?<!/)/*$`

Comment: It is not about greediness at all. It is a common regex behavior across many regex implementations. No regex is necessary: `if not text.endswith('/'): text = f'{text}/'`. Else, simply pass the `count` argument set to `1`: `re.sub('/*$', '/', url, count=1)`.